# Question regarding the application of Time Reversal Operator in Expectation Value of Operator in QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, time-reversal-symmetry

I just want to make sure I understand what I am doing. Let me write down how I think things should work, and please spot any mistake in my thought process once I make any.

Say I have some state
$$
\langle \psi_1 | \hat{A} | \psi_2 \rangle
$$
and I want to insert $\mathcal{T}^{-1} \mathcal{T}$ in the matrix element, where $\mathcal{T}$ is the antiunitary time-reversal operator. Then I have

$$
\langle \psi_1 | \hat{A} | \psi_2 \rangle = 
\langle \psi_1| \mathcal{T}^{-1}\mathcal{T}\hat{A}\mathcal{T}^{-1}\mathcal{T} |\psi_2\rangle= (\langle \psi_1 | \hat{A} | \psi_2 \rangle)^*
$$
where $^*$ denotes complex conjugation. Now let me modify the above equations such that
$| \psi_2 \rangle = | \psi_2(p) \rangle$ where $p^{\mu} = (E, \vec{p})$,
$| \psi_1 \rangle = | \psi_2(p') \rangle$ where $p^{\mu} = (E', \vec{p}')$, and
$\hat{A} = \hat{A}(z)$ where $z^{\mu} = (t, 0, 0, z)$

I expect time reversal to act on each kinematic variable (or space-time) in the following way
$$
(E, \vec{p}) \rightarrow (E, -\vec{p});\quad
(E', \vec{p}') \rightarrow (E', -\vec{p}');\quad (t, 0, 0, z) \rightarrow (-t, 0, 0, z)
$$
Denoting this transformation of variables with the subscript $_t$, we can write the expectation value of $\hat{A}$ as
$$
\langle \psi_1(p') | \hat{A}(z) | \psi_2(p) \rangle = 
(\langle \psi_1(p_t') | \hat{A}(z_t) | \psi_2(p_t) \rangle)^*
$$
This remains true even when
$\hat{A}(z) = \bar{\psi}(-z/2)\gamma^{\mu}\psi(z/2)$.

Did I make any mistake anywhere?

Comment: $TT^{-1}=I$ Is linear so that I do not understand the final complex conjugation in the second formula...

Comment: With the operator, one has $T A T^{-1} = U A^* U^{-1}$ where $U$ is unitary (time evolution) operator. Furthermore, one has $T | \psi(t) \rangle = T U(t)|\psi(0) \rangle = T U(t) T^{-1} T | \psi(0) \rangle  = U(t)^{-1} | \psi(0) \rangle^*$. Combining both should give me the above result.

Comment: So for me $A$ is a non-local quark bilinear. I _dont_ think it is Hermitian. For context, I am trying to prove that the generalized parton distribution is even in skewness, refer to this review [https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0307382] (https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0307382)

Comment: What does $A^*$ mean?

Comment: And also $|\psi\rangle^*$?

Comment: Let me answer both separately. $A$ is a linear operator acting on a Hilbert Space. If we denote $a_{n,m}$ a matrix element of $A$, then $A^*$ would mean $a_{n,m}\rightarrow a_{n,m}^*$ for all $n, m$.

Comment: $| \psi \rangle$ is a ray living in a Hilbert Space. We can choose a basis for that ray to be something like $| \psi \rangle = \sum_{n=1}^2 c_n | n \rangle$ where $| n \rangle = (\alpha_n, \beta_n)$ for example (say it's a 2-D Hilbert Space). Then $| \psi \rangle^* = \sum_{n=1}^2 c_n^* (\alpha_n^*, \beta_n^*)$.

Comment: Ok, $A^*$ is the operator whose matrix is the complex conjugated of that of $A$. This notion strictly depends on the used basis whereas you seem to deal with a generic vector...

Comment: However, the problem is with your second formula. Now I cannot continue to discuss. I suggest you to edit your post to completely expand  that passage since the problem is there.